# how to query the values which are having two double quotes at the end of the string like '"My test value ""'?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I wanted to query the values in the column which is having two double quotes at the end of the string?

Example:

```
ID-->Name
1001, This is Test Data""
1002, This is test 2 data"
1003, This is test 3 data""
```

output of the query should be:

```
1001, This is Test Data""
1003, This is test 3 data""
```

Answer (score 1):

If the start of each entry is marked by four digits, you could use:

```
/\d{4}[^"]*""/
```

(Four digits, followed by any number of characters other than quotation marks, followed by two quotation marks.

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/ijIBZf/1

Comment: why need the match for four digits? Just searching the `""` seems to be enough ?

Comment: When I wrote the answer there were no line breaks in the example input (see edit history). If each entry is on a new line the refer could just be /.*""$/